# FedEx shipping integration

Tags: php, codeigniter, fedex

I am trying to get shipping quotes from FedEx. I found [this](http://www.varnagiris.net/2006/06/01/php-fedex-shipping-rates-calculator/) library where it seems to be doing exactly what i want, but it's not working (in the comments below, the developer notes that the FedEx API has changed). Using said library I get a: `Error 405--Transaction data not found` when ever I try and send the request.

Is there an how do I go about getting quotes from FedEx - The FedEx dev center is horrible, I can't find anything I'm looking for (finding the documentation would be a nice start :P ) and the files they give you to download don't make much sense - I'm looking for an example of working PHP code.

It was recommended by a friend to just do this in a simple `POST` request - is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FedEx no longer supports the older XML or tagged transactions. You must send requests using web services. The dev center gives you everything you need, including sample code in PHP.

From this [page](https://www.fedex.com/wpor/web/jsp/drclinks.jsp?links=wss/getstarted.html), scroll to the bottom and select the "Download code in..." PHP

Comment: I've done that, but the code is messy and fairly unreadable - I looked through it and couldn't find where I was to change/add my data into it